# pod install fails in integrated vs terminal

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, cocoapods, pod-install

I'm trying to run a pod update from my integrated VS-code terminal (react-native project) but it keeps throwing this error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936   throw err;   ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/.../App/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js Debugger attached. Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

Node.js v17.6.0

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 859: unexpected token at ''.

target 'appname' do

config = use_native_modules!       use_react_native!(
```

I already tried removing package-lock.json, node_modules, and reinstalling.

If I run the command in a normal terminal I have no problems, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

**step 1:** pod deintegrate

**step 2:** pod install